# Replacing the System.Timers.Timer.Elapsed event when inheriting System.Timers.Timer

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, .net-4.0, overriding

I'm creating a new class so that I can make the System.Timers.Timer class fit my needs just a little bit better.  I create my new class like so...

```
using System.Timers;

class BtElapsedEventArgs : ElapsedEventArgs
{
    //My extras
}

namespace MyGreatNewTimer
{
    class BetterTimer : Timer
    {

    }
}
```

Now I simply want to replace the `Elapsed` event that fires elsewhere.

```
private void TestTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  //Timer has elapsed
}
```

I want it to produce the following...

```
private void TestTimer_Elapsed(object sender, BtElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  //Timer has elapsed
}
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Follow [How to: Publish Events that Conform to .NET Framework Guidelines (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx)

Comment: @RezaAghaei I know how to create events in my class and fire them off.  That was not the question.  I want to know how to override one that already exists in another class (or in my case the base aka inherited class).  The link you provided does not tell you anything other then how to create a class with events.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, The answer is the same, you need to create your own `Elapsed` event that shadows the original event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can follow [How to: Publish Events that Conform to .NET Framework Guidelines (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx) and create your own `Elapsed` event and hide the original `Epalsed` event:

```
namespace MyGreatNewTimer
{
    class BtElapsedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public DateTime SignalTime { get; set; }
        //Some other properties
    }
    class BetterTimer : Timer
    {

        new public event EventHandler<BtElapsedEventArgs> Elapsed;

        public BetterTimer()
        {
            base.Elapsed += BetterTimer_Elapsed;
        }

        void BetterTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = this.Elapsed;
            if(handler!=null)
            {
                var bte = new BtElapsedEventArgs() { SignalTime = e.SignalTime};
                //Set other properties, then fire the event
                handler(sender, bte);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect and exactly what I was looking for.  I guess when you create a class that inherits another and create an event it hides the underlying base class's event?  Either way this got me exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: When you define a member with the same name of the member in base class, you hide or shadow the base class member. You are welcome :)

Comment: [**new Modifier (C# Reference)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx)

When used as a declaration modifier, the new keyword explicitly hides a member that is inherited from a base class. When you hide an inherited member, the derived version of the member replaces the base class version. Although you can hide members without using the new modifier, you get a compiler warning. If you use new to explicitly hide a member, it suppresses this warning.

Comment: By the way, `ElapsedEventArgs` has not a public constructor and you can not inherit from it. `The type 'System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs' has no constructors defined`

Comment: I know that but if my edit is not in place this answer is wrong and will not compile.  In my edit I never tried to inherit  `ElapsedEventArgs`, I edited to inherit the `EventArgs` class.  Have you actually tried the code you posted?  It will not compile!

Comment: Suggest your edit again and I'll accept it. I mistakenly thought you are inheriting from `ElapsedEventArgs` as you did in question, my mistake, sorry about that. But you should know it is not compulsory to derive from event args, and I tested the code and it works properly but it's better to follow guidelines and inherit from `EventArgs`.

Comment: Thanks.  I wonder why I get the `no implicit reference conversion` error without adding it and you don't.